# Mongodb server version not upgraded in mac

Tags: mongodb

I updated MongoDB to 3.4.10 using HomeBrew

1. brew update
2. brew upgrade mongodb

When I check db.version() it says 3.0.6.

But When I run 'mongo' command it says Shell version - 3.4.10 and server version - 3.0.6. Server and Shell version do not match. I want to use aggregate commands that is not supported in version 3.0.6.

So any one knows the answer reply here. Thank you :)

Comment: I am not sure what might be happening.  The recommendation is to migrate firstly from 3.0 to 3.2, and then, 3.2 to 3.4.

Comment: Could it be that it's simply the server was never shut down during the install and thus the old process is still the one running in resident memory? You might try actually shutting down the server instance and restarting, But as noted, you really should have processed a gradual upgrade, but if the data is not important on a development instance then it really should not be a problem. Upgrade guidelines are really for production servers where data is important.

Comment: I shutdown the server and tried and also I uninstall the mongodb using "brew uninstall mongodb" and install again. But it still says the same thing